# Its possible to use PGN EXTRACT to generate split variants and random?

Tags: pgn-extract

I'm using [pgn-extract](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/) to generate a lot of positions from my theory. I would like to know if it's possible to randomize the result for losing patterns of this.

Answer (score 1):

pgn-extract can split a game with variants into separate games, but it does not have any randomisation features, unfortunately.